# Can Jenkins just pull commit from AWS CodeCommit and push to EC2 instance?

Tags: jenkins, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

I have tried AWS CodeDeploy along with CodePipeline to push my latest commits from CodeCommit to my web server running on EC2, but this process is tedious and take my EC2 offline momentarily.

All I want to just run **git pull** from my EC2 and nothing more without going all this pipeline hassle.

Can Jenkins do this in-easy way?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Linux EC2 instance running ssh daemon, you can 'scp' files to the EC2 instance from Jenkins shell commands. There may be a plugin to make your life easier with this process.

Answer (score 0):

Code Deploy gives you access to auto scaling group and integration, as well as options like green blue.. A copy can be done, assuming permissions and ip firewall allows it always and it will be faster.. But you can't react to scaling if wildly successful as easily